# Change Parent Collection View cell background color when select child tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

*I have the parent custom Collectionviewcell and inside I have the child custom Tableview. When I click table view I need to change the background color of collectionviewcell and tableview row background. I am trying achieve using gesture for tableview. but its not working.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with protocols
first your tableview inform the collection cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  backgroundColor = .red
  delegate?.didSelectItem(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

then on your collectionView Cell

```
func didSelectItem(indexPath: IndexPath) {
  self.backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use didSelect of tableView?
Some code should be easy to see how you use gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one main array, inside created another array for table content, and manage selection on tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath).

Please check demo : https://github.com/karan7698007/CollectionViewDemo.git